# Dual boot with ubuntu and windows 7

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

Recently I bought Dell vostro 1550 model which was shipped with Ubuntu os. But now I want to install Windows 7 also along with Ubuntu. I am having single 320 gb hdd on which Ubuntu installed. Now I want to partition this Ubuntu boot drive to install Windows 7 as well. I tried with gparted but boot drive not showing any option to partition., Please help me how can I solve this.

Answer (score 3):

The absolutely easiest way to solve this is to just install windows 7 on the drive (thus wiping ubuntu) and during the installation, you use the windows installation program to format the disk (to for example two partitions). After you've installed windows you can install ubuntu on the unused partition.

However, I do think this question would fit the power user site more.

Comment: And.... migrated! Now someone with proper knowledge can answer :)

Comment: Yeah, the Windows installer doesn't like playing second fiddle to another installed OS.